# Что такое тип функции с++

Tags: c++, стандарт

Недавно, изучая стандарт, а точнее пункт `3.9.2 Compound types`, я наткнулся там вот на такую запись:

```
Compound types can be constructed in the following ways:
- functions, which have parameters of given types and return void or references or objects of a given
type
```

И я немного запутался, не могли бы вы мне разъяснить о чем тут идет речь и почему функции берут как составной тип?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/q/52250480/7485582

Comment: Не особо понимаю вопрос. Тут просто написано, что существуют типы-функции. И что их возвращаемые типы и типы параметров - это, собственно, типы. Например, если у вас есть `int foo(int) {}`, то `decltype(foo)` дает как раз такой тип `int(int)`.